# How to integrate Apache IoTDB with Nifi to use `PutIoTDBRecord` and `QueryIoTDBRecord` processors?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I checked the official guide and know that Apache IoTDB can be integated with Apache NiFi using `nifi-iotdb-bundle` tool. I want to ask, if I want to use the two processors, `PutIoTDBRecord` and `QueryIoTDBRecord` mentioned in the official guide, what needs to be configured in Nifi before using these processors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of Apache IoTDB has been included in the Nifi library, so Nifi should already include the processors you want by default. You can check in the Nifi library, and if not included, you can create a `nar` package, drag it to Nifi and restart it.